# Weird NullPointerException not hints (null's in data of the arrayadaptor on spinner)

Tags: android, android-layout

Exception, nothing beyond this. Normally logcat has more useful information, but in this case, sadly not much.

```
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:192)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1074)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:296)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-06 13:26:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The start of my layout xml is (I suspect something silly missed out in the first half of xml) journey.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            //Skipped some code I think wont help debug this
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/startInMinutes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
```

The first activity, calls this activity. The first few lines of the activity below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.journey);
    // Some more code
    // Adapter related code for ListView
    vehicleListView = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.vehicleList);
    vehicleListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, vehicleList));
    vehicleListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    vehicleListView.setSelection(0);
```

Edit : Root cause was, vehicleList array had null values.

Comment: post more code of your Activity.

Comment: What about the rest of the xml?

Comment: You need to post more of your XML file if you want help.

Comment: I am trying to reduce the amount code and xml. I have just edited, if it does not help, I'll it all.

Comment: Is there something to do with "startInMinutes.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);" I changed it from adapter.setOnItemSelectedListner(this)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `NullPointerException` appears most likely because you have `null` values in the `array`/`List` that you pass in the `ArrayAdapter`'s constructor for one of your `Spinners`.

By default an `ArrayAdapter` will call the method `toString` on the data items and use that to set the text on the row's `TextView` if the type of data for the `ArrayAdapter` is not of type `CharSequence`.

Print the values of your data arrays(`vehicleList` and `Globals.TIME_WINDOW`) and make sure you don't have `null` values in  them.

Comment: Bangon, vehicleList array had all null's. I just hope android would throw a more meaningful exception point out the exact source..

Answer (score 1):

There must be some other stuff missing that you should post. Can't really debug your error just from that (both the XML and JAVA files).
However, just from looking at your XML, seems like you can just use a RelativeLayout inside of your scrollview because you are doing a lot of LinearLayout nesting. Which anytime you have to draw more views, it's not only hard to go though (which it happening now) but also hurts the performance of your app.

Comment: Nope, thats what is weird about this exception, nothing more than what I have reported.

Answer (score 1):

I still think the problem is with the xml, but let's go:

1 - I don't see any vehicleList id Spinner on your xml. Are you sure this id exists?

2 - I think this vehicleList in your activity is an array? Did you populate it? Or is it null?

3 - Maybe the problem could be the startInMinutes spinner with a Long Array.