# Android - populating a spinner from a database function returning an array dynamically

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, spinner

I have a `database` filled with certain values and I wondered how i can put them in a `spinner`. I have a class called `SetSql` which holds all of my database functions, and in it a function called `getProfiles()`,  which returns a `String Array`. Now, I also have a `spinner` on my page with the id of `spinner1`, and I wondered how can i populate it from that `getProfiles()` Functions?

Also i must note that the number of items in the database is not known, and could range from 0 to practically anything.

Thanks!

---

**My efforts**

```
    SetSql getprofiles = new SetSql(this);
    getprofiles.open();
    if(getprofiles.getProfiles().length>0){
        spinnerArray = new String[100];
        spinnerArray = getprofiles.getProfiles();
    }else{
        spinnerArray = new String[1];
        spinnerArray[0] = "No Profiles, Please Create One";
    }
    getprofiles.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
    array.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    profiles.setAdapter(array);
```

**My getProfiles()**

```
public String[] getProfiles() throws SQLException{
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_USER};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_USERS, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID);
    String[] result = new String[100];

    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER);
    int count = 0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){ 
        result[count] = c.getString(iName);
        count++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please remember that this function is a part of a class, so some vars like the KEY_Xs and ourDatabase are not in here.

**LOGCAT**

```
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:192)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-07 23:03:25.691: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If you have any idea why this should crash, I would love to hear :D

Comment: Some kind man helped me find the answer, thread in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272473/android-spinner-crashing-when-clicked-on?noredirect=1#comment21583370_15272473

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String[] myArray = {"some","values"};

Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,myArray);

spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can also use a `List` instead of `String[]`

Comment: Please look at my source. Do you have any idea why this could be crashing?

Comment: just shooting in the dark but did you initialized the 'profiles' Spinner? Edit: anyway, i recommend debugging your app adding some Breakpoints wherever you want. Also, try to remove the DB part using a simple Array and see if it crashes. Also trying with the DB part, without the Spinner and see if it crashes, etc...

Comment: The spinner is initialized, and using an already populated array like you did most certainly works. I will try debugging, but please see if you can find any other possible errors :)

Comment: Using the debugger showed nothing unusual.. Then again, i am not familiar with this debugger and i don't really know how to use it.

Comment: your spinnerArray is null. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11363800/999516